# Store variables from MySQL select to PHP class variables more efficiently when the table field names are identical to the class variable names?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am selecting data from a database.  The database field names are exactly the same as the class variable names.  Is there a way to store this data into the class variables without specifying each one individually?

```
    //gets info about a specified file.
    //chosen based on a supplied $fileId
    function getFileInfo($fileId)
    {
        //select info from database
        $sql = "SELECT id, companyId, url, name, contentType, fileSize, saved, retrieved
                FROM files
                WHERE id = $fileId";
        $results = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
        $results = $results->fetch_object();

        //store info into class variables
        $this->id = $results->id;
        $this->companyId = $results->companyId;
        $this->url = $results->url;
        $this->name = $results->name;
        $this->contentType = $results->contentType;
        $this->fileSize = $results->fileSize;
        $this->saved = $results->saved;
        $this->retrieved = $results->retrieved;
    }
```

Comment: I vaguely recall finding a mysqli method that will do this but i can't find it now.

Comment: @Brian `mysqli_fetch_object` has an optional class arg but it has to be a string looking at the code example I don't think it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose this approach:

```
$nameMap = array(
   'id',
   'companyId',
   'url',
   'name',
   'contentType',
   'fileSize',
   'saved',
   'retrieved',
);

foreach( $nameMap as $attributeName ) {
   $this->$attributeName  = $results->$attributeName ;
}
```

While one could write

```
foreach($result as $var => $value) {
...
}
```

the outcome fully depends on backing table's structure. If you add further attributes to the table, your code might break.

Using `$nameMap`, the application still works.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way would ba a loop:

```
foreach($result as $var => $value) {
    $this->$var = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `foreach` structure:

```
foreach ($result as $column => $value) {
  $this->$column = $value;
}
```

Not nice but will work.

Answer (score 1):

Humm.  Well, PDO has native functions for that, if you're not married to mysqli for some reason:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print $result->NAME;
```

The biggest disadvantage I've found is that PDO doesn't support SSL connections between the PHP machine and the MySQL machine.

Comment: On the bright side, it's fairly common to run the database server and the web server on the same machine, so that's not always a problem.

Comment: @Sam Dufel True. Still worth mentioning, though.