# Can you define class variables from within a class method in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to pull all info about a file from a files table, but that table's structure might change.

So, I'd like to pull all the field names from the table and use them to generate the class variables that contain the information, then store the selected data to them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643132/store-variables-from-mysql-select-to-php-class-variables-more-efficiently-when-th/6643211#6643211

Comment: You can just write `$this->someVar = 'foo';` and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample**

```
<?php

    class TestClass
    {

        public $Property1;

        public function Method1()
        {

            $this->Property1 = '1';
            $this->Property2 = '2';

        }

    }

    $t = new TestClass();
    $t->Method1();

    print( '<pre>' );
    print_r( $t );
    print( '</pre>' );

?>
```

**Output**

```
TestClass Object
(
    [Property1] => 1
    [Property2] => 2
)
```

As you can see, a property that wasn't defined was created just by assigning to it using a reference to `$this`. So **yes, you can define class variable from within a class method**.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, see php overloading.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Quick Example: ( Not this isn't great usage )

```
<?php

class MyClass{
    var $my_vars;

    function __set($key,$value){
        $this->my_vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    function __get($key){
        return $this->my_vars[$key];
    }
}

$x = new MyClass();

$x->test = 10;
echo $x->test;

?>
```

Comment: I believe you can actually skip the __get and __set altogether and get exactly the same behavior.  You only need to define those if you want behavior more complex than just retrieving exactly what was set.

Comment: True True, I personally like to do it this way. :)

Comment: But this isn't an example of "defining a property from within a class method", is it? This is rather an example of using the magic methods to dispatch the retrieval/definition of nonexistent properties, from outside the class.